# Adding "-pie" to the linker flags in YOCTO

Tags: security, linker, yocto, flags

I am trying to add compiler and linker flags to all packages in YOCTO.
Currently, I am doing it in the machine.conf by adding:

TARGET_CFLAGS_append = " -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIE"
TARGET_LDFLAGS_append = " -pie -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro "

When I add the "-pie" option to the LDFLAGS, I get the problem that also the shared libraries are linked with the "-pie" flag which results in an error.

How can I force Yocto to add the "-pie" linker flag when linking executables but not when linking libraries?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre existing policy for hardening which enables PIE support as well.
You can enable it by

```
require conf/distro/include/security_flags.inc
```

in one of global configuration metadata files e g. `local.conf`